# Skype window problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype, system, window

Skype app in my Ubuntu system work perfectly. But today when I run the app, I see this:

[image: skype window]

How Can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure reinstall helps? I have latest skype installed and i have this problem. skype.com doesn't allow to download newer version. only my current

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk In u-d13 post I see Java process in Terminal. So propably you using something which run java in background. Every time when I run IDE which based in Java, first I run skype.

Comment: I guess [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/694231/339319) is the solution for your problem, at least it was in my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps have helped [other people who had similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning):

1. Get the PID of the last process to use the shared memory segment (`lpid` — should be the last column):

   ```
   ipcs -mp|tail
   ```
2. Find out what process is that:

   ```
   ps aux|grep <lpid>
   ```

   where `<lpid>` is the PID of the last process.
3. Terminate the process either by closing the offending application or executing

   ```
   kill <lpid>
   ```

Comment: it helps. but seems i have to repeat this each time when skype stops to work.