# How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, skype

For some reason I have graphical issues with Skype. I had less of them 3 days ago and thought that if I reboot pc everything will work fine. But it didn't hit the mark. While reinstalling Skype I can see such picture right now:
[image]

I'm getting such error messages at console:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(skype:17186): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)
```

Comment: A quick google suggests the `Gdk-WARNING` is because of too many open shared memory segments and suggests setting shmall, shmmni: http://serverfault.com/questions/373375/how-to-set-shmall-shmmax-shmni-etc-in-general-and-for-postgresql

Comment: @AJefferiss do you think I can have such issue if I never changed this config and it was working fine before?

Comment: in all honesty I don't know, it might be a sign that a recent update in some app caused it to not clear up shared memory segments but I'm just guessing. Take a look at the output of `ipcs -m` to see how many segments you've got setup at the moment. You can also run `ipcs -mp` to see the PID of the last process to attach to a segment.

Comment: @AJefferiss you know, your comment helped, I will write my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got this problem with 2 simultaneous PyCharms running. So closing them is not a reasonable solution for me.
Using raus81's advice edited skype dash link:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

change

```
Exec=skype %U
```

to

```
Exec=env "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" skype %U
```

Comment: Tested on ubuntu 14.04, and Skype 4.3.0.37 (multiarch, for ubuntu 12.04 on skype download page). And worked fine. Thanks for you and @raus81

Answer (score 9):

It's a QT related problem, I fixed running skype with QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1

Start from shell:

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 skype
```

Comment: Great solution, works like a charm, thanks @raus81 ;)

Comment: I found this solved the same problem with other programs such as lyx.

Answer (score 6):

As AJefferiss suggested I executed a command:

```
ipcs -mp
```

I found a `"pid"` of last process and executed:

```
ps aux | grep "pid"
```

It was PyCharm, I was running 2 instances of this IDE. After I disabled one of them, Skype issue was resolved.

Comment: Hey did you find any permanent solution to this problem? It appears again and again

Comment: I think you should reduce amount of loaded memory. It helps for me.

Comment: I am just a beginner, can you please tell me where to do that?

Comment: @RSB If you check internet, there are other problems and solutions. But this was helpful for me. `ipcs -mp` it will give you a long list of processes which use shared memory, the most right columns is process pid. It's a number, like 878. I took the last one row. After it, you can find process name for that pid. `ps aux | grep 878`. Mine was PyCharm. I just closed it and everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is a bug in openjre-7u85: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1512760

According to the bug report there is someone working on this so it will be solved soon hopefully.

Comment: I have trapped in this issue on Debian with running Netbeans on `openjdk-7` with version `7u85-2.6.1-5`. With upgrading to `7u91-2.6.3-1` issue disappear. Thanks for link!