# Skype become ugly

Tags: skype

Something wrong happened to my skype:
[image: my poor skype]

Few days ago popup messages became appearing without text, just the grey box and smileys window also was wrong ( I didn't see any smile but the firsyt **:)**. So I decided to reinstall it, and I installed some libraries that seemed to solve issue (in x64 Ubuntu) :

```
> sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libxss1:i386 
> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386
```

But now everything became even even worse. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I think it's liked to this one [How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)

Starting from shell/terminal like this worked on my end:

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 skype
```

Other applications which depend on libqt4 seem to be affected as well (eg. VirtualBox). It's worth mentioning this is an Xorg problem though. Adding "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" to your system environment in /etc/environment/ should do the trick and you can just start Skype normally afterwards.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

then please add

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

After that save then please reboot

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. This thread helped me -
[How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)

I did a little trick: run Skype at first, then PyCharm.