# What's happen to my application Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

After updating my application media applications look like:

[image: clementine]
[image: vlc]

when i restart every thing looking good for approximately 5 hour of work and do the same again what should i do?

Comment: Clementine and VLC both use Qt. What about your other media apps?

Comment: smplayer the same the default music and video players run but no sound

Comment: Just to clarify - is this happening with all graphical applications, or just media player applications? Could you also specify which applications you updated?

Comment: i updated all application recommended in software updater like chrome , firefox, gimp and all default application with ubuntu like office ... etc this happen only with media application and ultracopier i think all apps use qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for a long time i found a great solution by append

```
env "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"
```

to Exec .desktop path

[reference here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)